# Why disabled attribute does not removed in modal?

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have modal where user can upload their file. As default, the upload button is disabled. So, when user have insert file, should be the button will be enabled. But this is not happen. Anyone please help.

I also have tried 2 methods below but not help.

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="modal-header">
    <h4 class="modal-title text-orange2">Upload ES Value File</h4>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
</div>
<form name="esvalueForm" id="esvalueForm" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="pd-20 bg-white border-radius-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-12 col-sm-12">
                    <div class="custom-file">
                        <input type="file" name="upload_file" id="esvaluefile" class="import-file" accept=".csv">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" id="btnUpload" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirmation-upload" disabled>UPLOAD</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**JS (2 methods)**

```
$("#esvaluefile").change(function() {
    if ($("#esvaluefile").val() == "") {
        $("#btnUpload").attr('disabled', true);
    }
    else {
        $("#btnUpload").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});

$("#esvaluefile").on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
    if ($("#esvaluefile").val() == "") {
        $("#btnUpload").attr('disabled', true);
    }
    else {
        $("#btnUpload").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});
```

Comment: Try `$("#btnUpload").attr('disabled', false);`

Comment: no changes happen

Answer (score 0):

Try to use prop()

```js
function toggleUploadButton() {
    $("#btnUpload").prop('disabled', $("#esvaluefile").val() == "");
}
$("#esvaluefile").change(toggleUploadButton)
    .on('show.bs.modal', toggleUploadButton);
```